# Java jdbc. how don't change record in database if variable is null?

Tags: java, forms, jdbc

I have a form with fields in which i am going to change the user values. 
But i don't specify value password field.
For example i changed some values and submit but don't changed password field.

```
<form action="/User" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${param.id}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="command" value="editUser"/>
  Full name: <input type="text" name="fullName" value="${param.fullName}"/><br/>
  Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br/>
                        name="role"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

So servlet recieves a null value in password variable and passes values in UserDao. 
I need that if password changed it must be changed in database, 
otherwise doesn't change.

```
public void updateUser(User user){
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update \"User\" set id_role = ?, fullname = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, user.getIdRole());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getFullName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getPassword()!=null ? user.getPassword() : "old password");
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, user.getId());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: You have to use two queries. With password update and without.

Answer (score 0):

Build your sql dynamically like the following and pass the values dynamic index.

```
public void updateUser(User user){
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("update \"User\" set id_role = ?, fullname = ? ");

    if (user.getPassword()!=null)
       sql.append("password = ? ");

    sql.append("WHERE id = ?"");

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update \"User\" set id_role = ?, fullname = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?");

  // declare index variable to get the dynamic index
   int index=1;
    preparedStatement.setInt(index++, user.getIdRole());
    preparedStatement.setString(index++, user.getFullName());

    if (user.getPassword()!=null)
        preparedStatement.setString(index++, user.getPassword());

    preparedStatement.setInt(index++, user.getId());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

In the above code we'll update the password when user changes password value otherwise password value is not going to update.

Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below through dynamic query building

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("update \"User\" set ");
    if(user.getIdRole()!=null){
        queryBuilder.append("id_role = ?,");
    }
    if(user.getFullName()!=null){
        queryBuilder.append(" fullname = ?,");
    }
    if(user.getPassword()!=null){
        queryBuilder.append("password = ?");
    }
```

and same for preparedStatment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As Sir Jens said in Servlet check if password is null or not and based on that either updateUserWithPass(User user) or updateUserWithoutPass(User user).

Partial Code

```
if(request.getParameter("password")!=null){
//Code for updateUserWithPass(User user);
}else{
//Code for updateUserWithoutPass(User user);
}
```